# Ranger Terminal file manager - Is it possible to run custom commands from file .bashrc?

Tags: python, linux, bash

Is it possible to "load" custom commands defined in .bashrc or any .sh file to Ranger?
To have access to those commands via ranger command bar?

Like
:mycustomcommand arg1 agr2
or
:shell mycustomcommand arg1 arg2

OR 
I need to recreate those with python and use Ranger's API?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is, but you will not see the output of the command:

```
:shell *your command and arguments here*
```

Alternatively just press `@`

The man page also covers adding a pause to check command output:

```
FLAGS

There are some additional flags that can currently be used
only in the "shell" command: (for example ":shell -w df")

 p   Redirect output to the pager
 s   Silent mode.  Output will be discarded.
 w   Wait for an Enter-press when the process is done
```

BTW this question was kinda answered [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/261091/execute-command-on-ranger-selection).

Comment: yeah I know I can invoke commands defined in /usr/bin/customcommand
but is there a way to load commands from a file?

Comment: From .bashrc aliases will work. However, if you mean you custom commands in the ranger only, then I am afraid ranger api is your only option:(

Comment: oh.. I think the fastest way is to split "functions" from .bashrc and rewrite em to /usr/bin/
But I can't find a solution to change directories in "current session" terminal. Always when I write custom commands in `/usr/bin/mycommand` and use `cd`  command actualy works in my "terminal background". I know its not that thread related but maybe u ve got some idea to work with current session?

Comment: I think custom commands are your only option. In case you want to try implementing your custom command, look [here](https://github.com/ranger/ranger/wiki/Custom-Commands)

Comment: yep, ur right. when I added to usr/bin it changes nothing it just starts new subshells and I cant anyway pass the outcome to ranger anyway. Custom commands for Ranger need to be created. thx for suggestions :)